# How to do better with this down-voted question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked this question and it has raised a good discussion among our friends and there were very good answers too. But it was down-voted unexpectedly.

I would like to know why so I can do better next time. And I know there is a similar question which was asked by me, even though it had good replies it also did not go where I wanted it to, and that's why I asked it in a different way, with some additional philosophical points that I struggled to understand.

---

Here is the question

> [Gender : Is it truly what it seems?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/13687/gender-is-it-truly-what-it-seems)

Answer (score 1):

A very fair meta question. I downvoted this question and I don't so a lot of downvoting really. For me I like to see questions that are to the point. If they are excessively verbose then I don't like them and don't think they are good questions. If I feel my attention waning halfway down then I feel my mouse point edging towards the down button arrow. Also I had a suspicion it was a duplicate question.

It is possible to have long questions that are great but I feel the same way about questions that I do about films. If you make a 3 hour film it's got to be pretty compelling and I'm always thinking - couldn't this be done in 90 mins. Similarly if you write a page for a question I think the question itself should be pretty amazing and insightful to justify that length. If not then edit it.

Also as a moderator I can't cast close votes without that vote becoming binding. So when I am in the case where I think the question isn't great but I'm not sure about closing it then my only option is a comment to that effect and maybe a downvote.

That said I really appreciate your input and I hope you aren't discouraged with the downvoting. Perhaps a net score of -4 is a bit extreme. I've certainly seen a lot worse with far higher scores. I guess a lot of people didn't like it so I would be interested to see comments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't know about the short and sweet, after all Godfather was a great movie :-) . I believe some feelings and explanations take both more time and words. But "@Crab" in other sites like "Reddit" it is allowed to ask long questions and people often do that. I must say i have seen a pattern in our SE, people tend to fall in line and follow the leader (I mean in some question or answer has like 2 or 3 up votes people usually follow and it is same about down voting). Sadly the trend is not done mindfully sometimes. May triple gems bless you!

Comment: @Theravada to be fair I'm aware that short question is a personal preference rather than any kind of site policy. I would imaging other users /moderators would have a different view. In fact I know they would. I do agree with the herd mentally thing. It's not too bad here but other sites are savage. Try answering on stack overflow main site on the JavaScript tag. Make a small mistake let the down votes fly. Alarming

Comment: @Theravada and I didn't like Godfather. Sorry - minority opinion I know

Comment: Ha ha! , never say that about godfather in a movie festival because there is a good chance of a murder :-)

Comment: Maybe a kindly written comment, to the effect that the question might be easier to follow if it was less lengthy, might be more helpful